# in emacs, append-next-kill sometimes prepends

Tags: emacs

For example, place point at the beginning of a line with the text "foo bar". Then M-d C-  C-e M-C-w C-w C-y produces " barfoo". This behaviour causes problems when I try to switch the order of text and when I combine a real kill with save-as-kill. No doubt prepending is often useful, but all the documentation I have found says that append-next-kill appends. How do I control emacs's choice between appending and prepending?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take some time to go through the [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help, [about] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: Seems some confusion WRT the right commands. Please tell which transforming is intended, so you might get some suggestions.

Comment: I may be confused about the commands, but what I wanted is to append. In the example, I first killed "foo" and then killed " bar", so I think append-next-kill should produce "foo bar". (If there were a command called prepend-next-kill, I would expect it to produce " barfoo". If I can't change the behaviour then I would like to understand how it decides whether to append or prepend.)

Comment: What about M-d M-f C-y? BTW having a look into append-next-kill, IMHO things really shouldn't be done that way - even if Emacs has more of this kind.

Answer (score 1):

See the Emacs manual, node `Appending Kills`.  It gives explicit examples, in particular an example that shows clearly what `C-M-w` is for and what it does.  Here is part of that text:

```
If a kill command is separated from the last kill command by other
commands (not just numeric arguments), it starts a new entry on the kill
ring.  But you can force it to append by first typing the command
`C-M-w' (`append-next-kill') right before it.  The `C-M-w' tells the
following command, if it is a kill command, to append the text it kills
to the last killed text, instead of starting a new entry.  With
`C-M-w', you can kill several separated pieces of text and accumulate
them to be yanked back in one place.
```

For `C-M-w` to append the next kill, that kill must *immediately follow* `C-M-w`.  If you do something else in between then there is no appending.  The command name might better have been `append-next-kill-if-it-follows-immediately`. ;-)

Comment: user3042937: You might like to `M-x report-emacs-bug` to have the function docstring updated, so that it also clarifies this point.

Comment: @phils: I was thinking that the doc already made this point sufficiently clear. Even in the passage I quoted here, it says "**right before it**".  But I guess I agree that it could be made even clearer -- so I did file a doc bug ([#15995](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15995)).

Comment: I read this documentation before. I agree that 'right before it' is already clear. My problem is that C-M-w sometimes prepends, which is not mentioned in any documentation I have seen.

Comment: Not clear (to me) what you mean. If you can give a reproducible recipe starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file), then I recommend that you use `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  `C-M-w` by itself neither appends nor prepends anything.  It just makes sure that, if the next command is a kill, that kill gets appended to the previous kill, instead of being added to `kill-ring` as a separate kill.

Comment: Replace third person singular verb by 'causes the next kill' plus infinitive where appropriate. When does the next kill append and when does it prepend?

My question already has an example: if you do not observe the same behaviour please let me know.

Comment: "When does the next kill append and when does it prepend?" The next kill **never** prepends AFAIK.  I think maybe you are still not understanding what `C-M-w` does.  It never does anything except what its doc says, and which I've rephrased a couple of times now.  It never causes one kill to be prepended to another.  If the following command is not a kill then `C-M-w` is a *no-op*.  This is not the place to belabor this.  I mentioned that I filed a doc bug.  If you feel that something different or something more should be communicated to Emacs Dev, please go for it: `report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: "The next kill never prepends AFAIK[?]." It does, as I showed by example at the very beginning of this discussion. (In emacs -Q:
Type "foo bar", then C-a M-d C-  C-e C-M-w C-w C-y.) I'm not forcing anyone to care about my question, so please stop cluttering this thread. Your doc bug is unrelated to my point, so I'll file my own.

Comment: I just now repeated your recipe in Emacs 24 (dev), 24.3, 23.4, and 22.3: `C-a M-d C- C-e C-M-w C-w C-y`.  You did not say what buffer to use, so I did that in `*scratch*`. No prepending. What's more, `C-h v kill-ring` shows no entry for anything prepended. You don't say what exactly you see, or what the starting point is (text, mode,...), or why you do `C- C-e`, or... Anyway, I have tried to help you, not clutter. I answered your question, "*How do I control emacs's choice between appending and prepending?*" (which should be the title): `C-M-w` *never* prepends -- that's how you "control" it.

Comment: Thank you for trying to reproduce the problem. To keep it as simple as possible, I typed the text & commands as shown with no preamble. (emacs -Q starts with *scratch* in Lisp Interactive mode. I saw the same behaviour in Text mode.) I don't know what more detail to give about what I see: " barfoo" is the yanked text, and the value of kill-ring is (" barfoo"). The example is designed for simplicity: my real use case involves a lot more text and movement between lines.

I'm puzzled that you don't see the same behaviour. I seem to have version 23.4.1.

Comment: OK, it sounds like a platform issue (bug in your Emacs version). I don't see it with Emacs 23.4.1 on MS Windows. `emacs -Q` starts in `*scratch*` but with point at the end of the buffer, two lines after the boilerplate text. I still don't understand why you do `C-e C-e` there. The `C-M-w` copies nothing when I do it, as it is at the end of the boilerplate last line. When I'm done with your recipe, `kill-ring` is only this: `(#("foo" 0 3 (fontified t)))`, that is, only `("foo")` (the string is propertized).

Comment: I agree that C-e C-e is pointless. I typed C-  C-e [set-mark-command, then move-end-of-line]. Point is at the end of the line, but mark is at the beginning, so C-w kills " bar".

Comment: I'm not sure whether the OS matters, but it's not MS:
Jorgens-MacBook-Air:chupacabra jorgenharmse$ sw_vers
ProductName: Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.7.5
BuildVersion: 11G63

Comment: I see what you see, now that you say that `C-` is `set-mark-command`. (`C-` is not a key sequence at all. I thought you meant `C--`. In `emacs -Q`, `C-SPC` is `set-mark-command`.) Yes, IMO it is a bug -- `foo bar` should be yanked.  The recipe to give for your bug report is as you wrote, but with `C-SPC`, not `C-`.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. It's a pity that notation slowed us down. (insert-kbd-macro uses "?\C-  ?\C-e" to show the sequence, but "C-SPC" is clearer.)

Comment: No doubt.  Had you written what `insert-kbd-macro` returns (a vector of chars, here) I would have understood: `?\C-e` is not the same as `C-e` etc. And `insert-kbd-macro` at least uses two spaces here (though strictly it does not need to).  Since you used what looks like Emacs *key-sequence* notation, I could only guess that by `C-` you really meant `C--`.  You might consider also clarifying your bug report, to save time.

Comment: From Leo Liu on the emacs team: Yes, prepend or append is dependent on the order of mark and point.
Maybe the documentation could be improved.